# Adding DGN format image to QT application

Tags: qt

Please suggest me how to load the DGN format image on to Qt Application. Because QT doesnt support this format. How to do this?. Is any QT image plugin available for DGN format. If so means please share with me.

Comment: If you need just rendering, without editing, you may create your own plugin.

Comment: I just want to move the image according to coordinates. How to create own plugin for this?. what all things required for this. I am new to this QT so.

Comment: DNG is not an image. It is CAD file. Do you want just to render it somewhere?

Comment: It is not DNG file, I want for DGN format. Yes i want to render it without editing it.

Comment: So you should write your own image plugin. I think that it is only one way.